# Determine datatype and use as a template typename

Tags: opencv, c++11, templates

I need to get a datatype from openCV [Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa6477efc7399fbe742418250ccf99a4b) type and use it later in an explicitly instantiated class:

```
template class Tensor<float>;
template class Tensor<uint16_t>;
template class Tensor<int8_t>;
```

I only have access to C++11 and am not allowed to use boost, so stuff like this is not possible:

```
std::map<int, std::any> cvToTypeMap = {{CV_32F, float}, //std::any <- C++17
                                       {CV_16U, uint16_t},
                                       {CV_8S,  int8_t}};
Tensor<cvToTypeMap[my_cv_mat.type()]> my_class_var(...);
```

The problem, as you see, is that I need this different types in my map.

If I am not mistaken, I also can't use `decltype(*my_cv_mat.data)` since it's `uchar`.

Any ideas now to achieve this?

Comment: Basically, you have an "abstract" `cv::Mat` and depending on the numerical type it holds, you want to create the relevant `Tensor` object? Does your `Tensor` class template inherit from a base `tensor` class?

Comment: @Rerito yes. In fact, I can also get the data type from JSON config file, but then I would need a `map<std::string, std::any>` again.. No, `Tensor` is independent class. A "wrapper" class for working with CUDA.

Comment: The problem I see here is that the output type changes, so at some point you will need type erasure

Comment: Can you embed the work you do on the tensor inside a "generic" function (akin to `void do_something(Tensor<blabla>, ...)`?

Comment: What you mean by "generic"? Currently the code is executed in `do_something(const Mat& data)` function. I can do with this function whatever I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to have a map of types, you could have a map of workers and code the `int` to numeric type mapping by hand. We then need a tensor builder that will take the `cv::Mat` to create the appropriate tensor object.

You will have to write a trait like the following:

```
template <int CVType>
struct int_to_numeric_type;

template <> struct int_to_numeric_type<CV_32F> { using type = float; };
template <> struct int_to_numeric_type<CV_16U> { using type = uint16_t; };
// ...
template <int CVType>
struct tensor_type {
    using type = Tensor<
                     typename int_to_numeric_type<CVType>::type
                 >;
};
```

Once this is done, the tensor builder can be worked out akin to this:

```
template <int CVType>
struct TensorBuilder {
    std::reference_wrapper<cv::Mat const> mat;
    TensorBuilder(cv::Mat const& matrix) : mat(matrix) {}

    typename tensor_type<CVType>::type make_tensor(/*Stuff other than matrix*/) const {
        // Extract all the stuff from mat you need and perform the numeric logic here
        return typename tensor_type<CVType>::type(...);
    }
};
```

Now, our tensor builders can be implicitly constructed from a `cv::Mat` object, we're gonna abuse that along with `std::function`. Let's get to the workers:

```
template <int CVType>
void do_work(TensorBuilder<CVType> builder /*, ... */) {
    auto tensor = builder.make_tensor();
    // Do whatever you fancy with your tensor (ie, that's the body of your actual function)
}
```

Then, we can embed these workers into a map of `std::function<void(cv::Mat const&/*, ...*/)>`!

```
std::map<int, std::function<void(cv::Mat const& /*,...*/)> > workerMap {
    {CV_32F, &do_work<CV_32F>},
    {CV_16U, &do_work<CV_16U>}
};
```

Usage is then:

```
// my_cv_map gets implicitly converted to TensorBuilder<...>, allowing the worker to work with the proper tensor type.
workerMap[my_cv_map.type()](my_cv_map /*,...*/);
```

Comment: Definitely a few black magic moments here for me. :D Will have to try it on my dummy repo. I think I found a place in my code that I can do `decltype(x)` off, so I won't use this approach. But that is irrelevant to the question and I think you answered it as good as it is possible. Marking as an answer.

Comment: The only subtle trick here is to trigger an implicit conversion from `cv::Mat` to `TensorBuilder<...>`. The builder might be needed because you will likely build your tensor object using information from the matrix, but not the matrix itself!